# Update only Chart.js without animations and without refreshing the browser

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chart.js2

I'm trying to update only Chart.js without needing to refresh the browser and without the reload animation of all the lines. I tried using the simple command chart.update(), but it keeps refreshing the browser and the animation. I want to do this in the simplest way possible. My data is coming from a database.
This is my chart:

```
<script>
    var newData = [<?php echo $datacor1;?>];
    var lbl = [<?php echo $labels; ?>];
    var ctx1 = document.getElementById('mychart1');

    var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx1, {
        type: 'line', 
        data: {
          labels: lbl,
          datasets: [
            {
              label: "Corrente 1",
              data: [<?php echo $datacor1;?>],
              borderWidht: 6,
              borderColor: 'red',
              backgroundColor: 'transparent'
            },
            {
              label: "Corrente 2",
              data: [<?php echo $datacor2; ?>],
              borderWidht: 6,
              borderColor: 'blue',
              backgroundColor: 'transparent'
            },
            {
              label: "Corrente 3",
              data: [<?php echo $datacor3; ?>],
              borderWidht: 6,
              borderColor: 'green',
              backgroundColor: 'transparent'
            },
            {
              label: "Corrente Total",
              data: [<?php echo $datatotcor; ?>],
              borderWidht: 6,
              borderColor: 'black',
              backgroundColor: 'transparent'
            },
          ]            
        },
        plugins: [

        ],
        options: {
          scales: {
            yAxes: [{
              ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true
              }
            }],
            xAxes: [{
              gridLines: {
                display: false
              }
            }]
          },

          title: {
            display: true,
            fontSize: 20,
            text: "Gráfico das Correntes"
          },

          labels: {
            fontStyle: "bold",
          },

          layout: {
            padding: {
              left: 0,
              right: 0,
              top: 0,
              bottom: 0
            }
          },
          tooltips: {
            enabled: true,
            mode: 'single',
            responsive: true,
            backgroundColor: 'black',
            titleFontFamily: "'Arial'",
            titleFontSize: 14,
            titleFontStyle: 'bold',
            titleAlign: 'center',
            titleSpacing: 4,
            titleMarginBottom: 10,
            bodyFontFamily: "'Mukta'",
            bodyFontSize: 14,
            borderWidth: 2,
            borderColor: 'grey',
            callbacks:{
              title: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                  return data.labels[tooltipItem[0].index];
              },
              afterTitle: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                var date = <?php echo json_encode($tempo) ?>

                return date[tooltipItem[0]['index']]; 
              },
              label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                    var label = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label || '';                  
                    if (label) {
                        label += ': ';
                    }
                    label += (tooltipItem.yLabel)+"A";                  
                    return label;
              }
            }
          },
          aspectRatio: 1,
          maintainAspectRatio: false
        }
    });

    function updateChart ()
    {
      window.myLineChart.update();
    };
    </script>
```

This is what I tried to update the Chart:

```
function updateChart ()
    {
      myLineChart.update();
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean by "it keeps refreshing the browser" - the `update` method only updates the chart. It in no way should be refreshing the whole page.

But you can prevent animation when calling `update` by passing `0` as the only parameter, as [documented](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html#preventing-animations):

> Sometimes when a chart updates, you may not want an animation. To achieve this you can call `update` with a duration of `0`. This will render the chart synchronously and without an animation.

Comment: I just don't know why it keeps refreshing my page. Weird

Comment: @Joao Without a reproducible test case it's difficult to help.

Comment: could you try to help me with this? If could have a look at my other post I would appreciate :)

Comment: I will try to make a JSBin file

Comment: this is the js bin file: https://jsbin.com/jofuzawibu/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Maybe I found out, It might be because I'm getting the data from the database or that just doesn't make sense

Comment: Just found out why It is because my button was inside a form in the HTML

Comment: Because you echo your data into the chart (via php) when the page is generated on the server. So the chart *does* update, but the data doesn't change. You'll need to fetch the data from your server via an ajax request.

Comment: So I would need to create an ajax only for the update right? Could I use this ajax for a real-time chart to?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, the button was inside a form in the HTML, that why it was refreshing the whole page.
Wrong example:

```
<div class="chart1">
      <canvas id="mychart1" ></canvas>
      <form method="POST">
        <p class="datafilter">Filtrar data:<input type="date" id="datafilter">
        <button type="submit" id="subfilt">FILTRAR</button></p>
        <button type="update" id="update" onclick="updateChart()">UPDATE</button>
      </form>
    </div>
```

Right example:

```
<div class="chart1">
      <canvas id="mychart1" ></canvas>
      <form method="POST">
        <p class="datafilter">Filtrar data:<input type="date" id="datafilter">
        <button type="submit" id="subfilt">FILTRAR</button></p>
      </form>
      <button type="update" id="update" onclick="updateChart()">UPDATE</button>
    </div>
```